# Backlight intel + acpi conflict

Tags: intel, 16.10, acpi, backlight

After Ubuntu Studio upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10 when I decrease the screen brightness, the backlight flickers rapidly. I can only use the two highest levels brightness. I installed brightness-indicator for troubleshooting but I would still use F5 and F6 keys.

In `/sys/class/backlight/` I have `acpi_video0` and `intel_backlight` folders. I guessed there is a conflict with these two folders that contain the same files. So I tried to rename `acpi_video0` in `acpi_video0.back`, but it's impossible to modify those files, permission denied even if I change permissions.

The cause of my problem may also have come from the manipulation I did before the upgrade. I followed this [tutorial](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/asus-ux510uw-n-ubuntu-16-04-review-setup.796871/):

> #### Function keys require GRUB edit
>
> Modify GRUB using command:
>
> ```
> gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to
>   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="`
>
> Update the GRUB with command:
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> Then Reboot
>
> This will take care of all function keys except the events for the
>   brightness keys...
>
> #### Brightness keys
>
> Create a config file using command:
>
> ```
> gksudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
> ```
>
> Place the following file contents:
>
> ```
> # begin file contents
> Section "Device"
> Identifier "card0"
> Driver "intel"
> Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
> BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
> EndSection
> # end file contents:
> ```

To give you more information about my configuration, I past an extract of my `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi= pci=noaer"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: if you think your previous action might have caused your problem, have you tried undoing it? What's the output of `cat /proc/cmdline` now? Do you still have that file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with those contents and have you tried `mv`ing it away from that directory to see what happens if it is not read?

Comment: The output of `cat /proc/cmdline` gives me `BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-26-lowlatency root=UUID=ddada60a-3bb1-4042-a44b-b5023bc8480c ro quiet splash acpi_osi= pci=noaer vt.handoff=7`

Comment: I already tried to move  `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` but that doesn't change any thing

Comment: Sorry, I should have said please [edit] your question to add information. Could you try removing the boot parameter `acpi_osi=` by the same procedure you did to add it (described in your question) and see how that affects things?

Comment: when I delet `acpi_osi=` my hotkeys don't work anymore

Comment: Hmm :S `acpi_osi=` is a big hammer as I understand... I wonder if any other `acpi_osi` [kernel boot parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt) would fix your problem, such as `acpi_osi=Linux`, but I don't know

Comment: did you find a fix for this?